# Issue resolving schema location when deploy SOAP client

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jboss

I am getting an issue when trying to deploy a soap client to JBOSS EAP 7.0.8

It appears that the issue is caused when trying to resolve the schema locations for XSDs referenced in the WSDL.

The error stack shows that the address it is trying to resolve has issues with the character decoding. Rather than the beginning of the URL showing http:// the ':' is encoded with '%3A' and the first slash is escaping the second (I think)

I am not deploying any specific webservice libraries with deployment but using EAP as the containing and the provided web services implementations.

```
10:04:30,890 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-4) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."ProvideDocs-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".INSTALL: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."ProvideDocs-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".INSTALL: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment "ProvideDocs-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:172)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:2032)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1955)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: JBWS024076: Service {http://company.uk/integration/claimsverification/PolicyInfoAPI}PolicyInfoAPI, cannot publish wsdl to: C:\jboss-eap-7.0.0\standalone\data\wsdl\ProvideDocs-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war\http%3A\qa3gwap01.bolt.company.uk%3A8080\pcsor\ws\com\company\uk\integration\claimsverification\PolicyInfoAPI%3Fwsdl
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.deployment.WSDLFilePublisher.publishWsdlFiles(WSDLFilePublisher.java:115)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.deployment.EndpointImpl.publishContractToFilesystem(EndpointImpl.java:148)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.deployment.EndpointImpl.doPublish(EndpointImpl.java:85)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.publish(EndpointImpl.java:255)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.publish(EndpointImpl.java:543)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.configuration.BusHolder.configure(BusHolder.java:235)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.deployment.aspect.BusDeploymentAspect.startDeploymentBus(BusDeploymentAspect.java:97)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.deployment.aspect.BusDeploymentAspect.start(BusDeploymentAspect.java:59)
    at org.jboss.as.webservices.deployers.AspectDeploymentProcessor.deploy(AspectDeploymentProcessor.java:73)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:165)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: JBWS022092: Could not resolve http%3A/qa3gwap01.bolt.company.uk%3A8080/pcsor/ws/com/company/uk/integration/claimsverification/../../../../../gw/xsd/backoffice/soapheaders.xsd in deployment ProvideDocs-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
    at org.jboss.ws.common.deployment.ResourceResolverImpl.resolve(ResourceResolverImpl.java:128)
    at org.jboss.ws.common.utils.AbstractWSDLFilePublisher.publishSchemaImports(AbstractWSDLFilePublisher.java:240)
    at org.jboss.ws.common.utils.AbstractWSDLFilePublisher.publishSchemaImports(AbstractWSDLFilePublisher.java:265)
    at org.jboss.ws.common.utils.AbstractWSDLFilePublisher.publishSchemaImports(AbstractWSDLFilePublisher.java:269)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.deployment.WSDLFilePublisher.publishWsdlFiles(WSDLFilePublisher.java:100)
    ... 14 more
```

Answer (score 1):

some things are there I can think first:

1. > Rather than the beginning of the URL showing http:// the ':' is encoded with '%3A' and the first slash is escaping the second (I think)

you are not correct. Escape goes only for \ not for /, but it can be just a mess with error message (probably it is) or somewhere in WSDL /XSD Schema Location configured like http:/qa3gwap01.bolt.company.uk... not http://qa3gwap01.bolt.company.uk

so try to check all schema location definitions you may have.

2. (kind of related to first one) 
   either:

   - somewhere in WSDL/XSD there is a schema location defined not as relative path to `../../../../../gw/xsd/backoffice/soapheaders.xsd` or
   - soapheaders.xsd is not in path from  WSDL/XSD file where that schema location is.
3. (Not sure about that, but...) As I remember EAR/WAR file in JBoss explodes not directly to the file system, but to its own vfs file system, so absolute path to schema location cannot be used. Try to keep schema locations as relative path and be sure it is available from WSDL/XSD where it is defined.
4. If XSD is on some real Http(s) Url and you are sure that it will be available all the time you have to have correct URL to it. Better way is to have XSD inside your WAR/EAR files, and point to them through relative path. Be dependent on outside URL at run-time is not a good idea.

Comment: First thing I checked was all the schema locations and their accessibility. I even set up another webservice with a relative path XSD and that gave me the same issue. At the moment I have managed to get this working but using a local copy of the wsdl and local copies of all the xsds of which there are many. I have a case open with Red Hat trying to solve this issue.

Comment: I guess it is only solution... BTW once in a while I had similar problem with Spring schemas in EAP 6, at every startup EAP tried to get Spring schemas from Internet, it was related to the fact that Spring uses schema location mapping from its own META-INF/spring.schemas in jar files. Solution was to import `META-INF**` in dependencies for `deployment/sub-deployments` in `jboss-deployment-structure.xml`to have that file in class path... but it was Spring specific... Still I guess have local copies somewhere available is correct, rather than get schemas from network...

Comment: Also I packaged as JAR file all my WSDLs and XSDs (with relative schema locations) into custom JBoss module,. then made a dependency reference to it in `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` and reference to them from classPath. And yes a lot of them are there...

Answer (score 1):

Bundle the WSDL and the XSDs in your WAR and use an xml catalog file to resolve the WSDL imports to the local XSDs.
If you are unsure how to do this, I recommend to give Netbeans a try. They have a great wizard which does all this for you.

See: https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/client.html#exploringthefacilities